# How to correctly format this quote?

Tags: support

I was answering a question that involved quoting form a [GCC doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) on the definition of one of the functions in it.

How do you correctly format that quote? I went with:

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_ctz (unsigned int x)`
>
> Returns the number of trailing 0-bits in x, starting at the least significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

Which was good enough for answering the question, but I would like to format it to match GCC just for pedantic and future answering purposes.

Answer (score 1):

What parts did you have difficulty with? As you already noticed, `code ticks` work inside a quote (note the original does not use `code`). So do **bold** and *italics*; the local formatting can be copied faithfully. The left indent may be for clarity in that long list only, and doesn't seem necessary in a single definition:

```
> — Built-in Function: int **__builtin_ctz** (*unsigned int x*)
>
> Returns the number of trailing 0-bits in *x*, starting at the least
significant bit position. If *x* is 0, the result is undefined.
```

> — Built-in Function: int **__builtin_ctz** (*unsigned int x*)
>
> Returns the number of trailing 0-bits in *x*, starting at the least
>   significant bit position. If *x* is 0, the result is undefined.

Seeing this, I'd say your proposed quote is better readable, with the exception you might want to use italics for *x*, or maybe signify it as code as well.